# How to use drop tables on target when via drush sql-sync?

Tags: database, drush

I'm using the following command::

```
drush sql-sync @prod @dev
```

As I experienced, it does not drop tables on target (@dev) machine.

Is there a way, while syncing this way, to drop tables on target, so databases match completely? Or I must manually first drop tables on target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drush sql-sync will not drop tables on the target unless you specify --create-db.  Note that the later drops and recreates the entire database; if you do not have permissions to do this, you could run drush sql-drop on the target first.

There has been a feature request to add this functionality (drop before sync) in the Drush issue queue for years: http://drupal.org/node/716412.  Patches welcome.

**Important update:**  On Drupal 7, if you drop tables on the target prior to sql-sync, you could run into trouble unless you have http://drupal.org/node/1996004#comment-7419764. This is fixed in 8.x-6.x-dev, but is not part of 5.9, 7.x-5.x-dev or 8.x-6.x-beta1.

**Update 2:** This fix has now also been committed to 7.x-5.x-dev.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed, I will se what I can do ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bash script that deletes all tables that are exist on @live, but do not exist on local:

```
drush sqlq "DROP TABLE $(comm -13 <(drush @live sqlq 'SHOW TABLES') <(drush sqlq 'SHOW TABLES') | paste -sd ',' - | sed 's/,/, /g');"
```

It assumes that you execute it after updating local database from @live, so after:

```
drush sql-sync @live default
```

It is helpful if you have no permissions to use --create-db.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Drush 8 with Drupal 7:

```
drush @dev sql-drop -y && drush sql-sync @prod @dev
```

**Careful, this will drop all tables on @dev without prompting (the -y flag).**